# How to get records which is not present in the table but present in another two table in sql server

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
MachineName
AQUA       
MAMMO      
NAZO789
```

Table 2

```
ShiftName
First
Second
Third
```

Table 3

```
Date           Shift         MachineName
21/08/2015     First            AQUA 
21/08/2015     First          NAZO789
21/08/2015     Second          MAMMO
21/08/2015     Second           AQUA 
21/08/2015     Third          NAZO789
```

Now I want the output for the date 21/08/2015 whose entries not in the table 3
for the MachineName and ShiftName

like as:

```
Date           Shift         MachineName
21/08/2015     Third           AQUA 
21/08/2015     Second         NAZO789
21/08/2015     First          MAMMO
21/08/2015     Third          MAMMO
```

Comment: Do you mean you want every combination of MachineName and ShiftName that does not appear in Table 3?

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server. Updated to give all missing combinations for a date range (including if nothing was present on a given date).

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE='21/08/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE='26/08/2015'

DECLARE @Dates TABLE (
    [DATE] DATE
)

DECLARE @counter int=0
WHILE DATEADD(DAY,@counter,@StartDate)<=@EndDate
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Dates SELECT DATEADD(DAY,@counter,@StartDate)

        SET @counter=@counter+1
    END

SELECT
   @Date [Date],sn.ShiftName,mn.MachineName
FROM MachineName mn
CROSS JOIN ShiftName sn
CROSS JOIN @Dates dt
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
      *
   FROM TABLE3
   WHERE Date>=@StartDate
   AND Date<=@EndDate
) dat ON dat.MachineName=mn.MachineName
    AND dat.[Shift]=sn.ShiftName
    AND dat.[Date]=dt.[DATE]
WHERE dat.MachineName IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. It works well with it. But what if i have FromDate and ToDate in table 3

Comment: @SwapnilGanjegaonkar This is why you received down votes by the way. You are not clear in what you are asking. And even with the comment, you are still not clear.If you have multiple dates, should it show all combinations missing for a each single day or missing across the time span?

Comment: Sorry for that actually i am not able to explain it clearly. I mean to say that if there are different dates in table number three(as in table i have shown you only one date as '21/08/2015' So instead of that if i have different dates). And  i am passing Parameters as FromDate and ToDate to the query. So how should get  the outupt ??? Did you get it now sir???

Comment: I understand you have multiple dates and you want to use a date range. However, what output are you expecting? All missing combinations per day or combinations for the entire span? So, if third shift and Aqua was present on the 21st, but not on the 22nd, would you expect it to show as a missing combination?

Comment: Actually there is an expectation by the user to enter the data for every MachineName for every Shift for every Date. And if there is no entry for any of these combination. Then i want to select those combination. Have you Got it sir?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all combinations that do not exist in Table3:

```
Select b.ShiftName,a.MachineNameFrom

    (Select MachineName,'join' as joiner
    From Table1) a

inner join

    (Select ShiftName,'join' as joiner
    From Table2) b

on a.joiner = b.joiner

EXCEPT

Select Shift,MachineName From
Table3
```